# Create a case-insensitive regular expression from a string in Ruby

Tags: ruby, regex

Let's say that I have an arbitrary string like

```
`A man + a plan * a canal : Panama!`
```

and I want to do a regex search for strings that are the same other than case. That is, this regular expression should match the string

```
`a man + A PLAN * a canal : PaNaMa!`
```

I take it the best approach is to backslash-escape every character with a special meaning in Ruby regular expressions, and then do `Regexp.new` with that string and `Regexp::IGNORECASE` as arguments. Is that right? Is there a tried-and-true regular expression for converting arbitrary strings into *literal* regular expressions?

By the way, I ultimately want to use this regular expression to do an arbitrary case-insensitive MongoDB query. So if there's another way I could be doing that, please let me know.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You can use `Regexp.escape` to escape all the characters in the string that would otherwise be handled specially by the regexp engine.

```
Regexp.new(Regexp.escape("A man + a plan * a canal : Panama!"), Regexp::IGNORECASE)
```

or

```
Regexp.new(Regexp.escape("A man + a plan * a canal : Panama!"), "i")
```

Comment: Thanks, that was just what I was looking for! (Though as to MongoDB, I realized that if I'm doing this kind of search often, I should really store a downcased version of the string for performance reasons.)

Comment: Used this in a clash of code competition :D

Answer (score 61):

Ruby regexes can interpolate expressions in the same way that strings do, using the `#{}` notation.  However, you do have to escape any regex special characters.  For example:

```
input_str = "A man + a plan * a canal : Panama!"
/#{Regexp.escape input_str}/i
```

Comment: This is such a great answer - it reads way better than the top voted response and feels more like Ruby to me to boot. Hope others will upvote this too..

Comment: I agree, I just upvoted this answer that now ties the accepted answer!  One more vote!

Answer (score 34):

If you know the regular expression you want already, you can add "i" after the expression (eg `/the center cannot hold it is too late/i`) to make it [case insensitive](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Options).

Comment: Right, but that's not the question I'm asking. I have an arbitrary string (from user input), not a regular expression. If the user enters `a+b`, for example, I want to be able to find `A+b`, `a+B`, or `A+B`, not `aaaaab`.

Comment: I can't unify what you wrote just above with your original question.  Consider revising your question?

Answer (score 10):

A slightly more syntactic-sugary way to do this is to use the `%r` notation for Regexp literals:

```
input_str = "A man + a plan * a canal : Panama!"
%r(#{Regexp.escape(input_str)})i
```

Of course it comes down to personal preference.